# Mongoid embeds_many Type Constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, type-constraints

I am trying to create an embeds_many relationship in mongoid and it appears to not be enforcing type constraints on the objects I add to the collection. Am I doing something incorrect here or is this by design?

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :extra_fields, class_name: "ItemType"
end

class ItemType
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :item
  field :type_name
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :schema_fields
  field :rabble
end


ruby > Item.delete_all
 => 1 

ruby > item = Item.new
 => #<Item _id: 4e20a60a401b3e47d2000004, _type: nil> 

ruby > item.extra_fields << Category.new(:rabble => 'derp')
 => [#<Category _id: 4e20a619401b3e47d2000005, _type: nil, rabble: "derp">] 

ruby > item.save
 => true 

ruby > item = Item.first
 => #<Item _id: 4e20a60a401b3e47d2000004, _type: nil> 

ruby > item.extra_fields[0].rabble
 => "derp"
```

Answer (score 0):

As MongoDB is schemaless, it's not strictly necessary for Mongoid to enforce the type of class added.  In your example you're only dumping `item.extra_fields[0].rabble`, it's set to `derp`. Since it's schemaless, it's not a critical failure in MongoDB that you're saving a field that exists in one model but not the other. If you do `item.extra_fields[0].class` you should see `ItemType` because it's using the `class_name` you set to determine the class used.

It could also simply be an oversight, I don't see any bugs posted along those lines on GitHub for Mongoid. You should post it over at https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues and let them know in case it is just a simple oversight.

Comment: Yeah this is possible. I have discovered that Mongo Mapper does enforce these kinds of association constraints to an extent, so playing with that for now.

Answer (score -1):

think class_name is not meant to validate, just an override that

indicates to mongoid that Item should look in ItemType class for the reverse relation
and not a class called ExtraField

yes Mongo doesn't innately have validation, but ActiveRecord doesn't truly add constraints to the underlying database either

like all things Ruby, deal with the power we're given